Different forms of Newton's algorithm
Newton's algorithm (e.g. Newton-Raphson) is often used for both root finding and optimization, although the form is slightly different in each of these. I am trying to understand why.
I tried to use basic logic to see this. In my opinion, everything comes down to the Taylor Expansion (i.e. Taylor expansion of the original function vs Taylor Expansion of the derivative of the original function):
$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3 + \frac{f^{(4)}(a)}{4!}(x-a)^4 + \cdots$$
$$f'(x) = f'(a) + f''(a)(x-a) + \frac{f'''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \frac{f^{(4)}(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3 + \frac{f^{(5)}(a)}{4!}(x-a)^4 + \cdots$$

For root finding:
Here, the goal is to find $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$.  The Taylor series expansion of $f(x)$ around $x_k$ is:

$$f(x) \approx f(x_k) + f'(x_k)(x - x_k)$$
We want to find $x_{k+1}$ such that $f(x_{k+1}) = 0$:
$$0 = f(x_k) + f'(x_k)(x_{k+1} - x_k)$$
Solving for $x_{k+1}$:
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$$

For optimization:
On the other hand, the goal is to find $x$ such that $f'(x) = 0$

The Taylor series expansion of $f'(x)$ around $x_k$ is:
$$f'(x) \approx f'(x_k) + f''(x_k)(x - x_k)$$
We want to find $x_{k+1}$ such that $f'(x_{k+1}) = 0$:
$$0 = f'(x_k) + f''(x_k)(x_{k+1} - x_k)$$
Solving for $x_{k+1}$:
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f'(x_k)}{f''(x_k)}$$
Thus, we can see the difference and similarities for both forms.
Thoughts?

This is correct. Another way of viewing the optimization algorithm is as extremizing the quadratic Taylor approximation at each step.

I'm not sure what the question is?

@m-stgt this is not a discussion site, that is what chat rooms are for.
